# Continuous Almost Everywhere on $A$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Show that if $f$ is continuous almost everywhere on $A$, then $f$ is measurable on $A$.

We define a set $B$ to be the set of all $x\in A$ such that $f$ is not continuous on these $x$ . By definition of continuous almost everywhere, $f$ is continuous at all $x\in A\backslash B$, $m(B)=0$.  Then $\{x\in A|f(x)>c\} = \{x\in A\backslash B|f(x)>c\}\cup\{x\in B|f(x)>c\}$. Since $\{x\in B|f(x)>c\}\subseteq B$ and $m(B)=0,$ it follows that $\{x\in B|f(x)>c\}$ is measurable and has measure 0. Since $f$ is continuous on $A\backslash B$, it follows that $f$ is measurable on $A\backslash B$ and hence $\{x\in A\backslash B|f(x)>c\}$ is measurable. Since union of measurable sets is measurable, it follows that $\{x\in A|f(x)>c\}$ is measurable. Therefore, $f$ is measurable on $A$.

Is my proof correct ?

Edit : Sorry for my wrong statement of problem. I am proving "almost everywhere."

Comment: It should be "almost everywhere" and not "everwhere". Also, you can't say "$f(x)$ is not continuous" instead of "$f$ is not continuous at $x$". Your proof isn't correct because it doesn't make sense at all. Please try to rewrite it more carefully in a rigorous way so that it makes more sense.

Comment: I believe I see the mistake more clearly now. Is the correct problem statement "if $f$ is continuous almost everywhere on $A$, then $f$ is measurable on $A?$" Because if so then your proof is indeed correct (modulo the grammar mistakes pointed out by elidiot) and this has all just been a misunderstanding.

Comment: @D.Brogan
Yes, the correct statement is if "f is continuous almost everywhere on A, then f is measurable on A. " In my lecture notes, my lecturer have provided me with the proof of "f is continuous on A, then f is measurable on A." So after clearing all the misunderstanding , is my proof valid ?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is not correct. First, $B$ is just the empty set. Second, you state in your proof "since $f$ is continuous on $A\setminus B,$ $f$ is measurable on $A\setminus B.$" It seems here you're using the result you're trying to prove.

A better strategy might be to show that the preimage under $f$ of Borel sets is measurable. You can do this by making use of the fact that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for open $U.$

Comment: the theorem that if $f$ is continuous on $A$, then $f$ is measurable was proven before in my lecture notes. Can't I just use the that theorem to prove the case for almost everywhere?

Comment: @LingMinHao You are asked to prove the statement "if $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is measurable." If you already have that as a theorem then there is nothing to prove. I suspect either you are not allowed to use that theorem, or you're misunderstanding either that theorem or the problem statement.

Comment: @LingMinHao It should also be noted that there is no "almost everywhere" case. This question is about a property that a function either has or does not have. It is not a local question.

Comment: @D.Brogan $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is continuous almost everywhere on $\mathbb R$, but not everywhere continuous.

Comment: @D. Brogan. The inverse image of an open set is not open for an almost everywhere continuous function!

Comment: Yes I understand this. However the question read "if $f$ is continuous everywhere on $A$, then $f$ is measurable on $A$" when I typed this answer up. The edit made completely changes the problem.